# How do i hit the server(Dot Net Web API) with xamarin app using url?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**In Xamarin**

```
var bcc = "Sandeep Subbiah";
var usb = "http://localhost:53325/";
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(bcc, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
HttpResponseMessage reponse = await client.PostAsync(usb, stringContent);
```

**In Dot Net Web API**

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/Values/UploadFile")]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(string file)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "success"});
        }
```

*How do i get the contents from **Xamarin** to **Dot Net Web API** and return the **SUCCESS** message back to Xamarin*

Comment: `"http://localhost:53325/"` do you know what `localhost` means?

Comment: this might be his first time doing api

Comment: @VladMatvienko localhost is the Local PC.

Comment: @jayvee yeah it's the first time i'm doing this

Comment: no, you are wrong. Localhost is the device, on which you are running the code. If you run it on Android phone, then it will point to Android phone. And that likely is your problem.

Comment: If you had multiple `local PCs`, to which one would `localhost` point, if you were right?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Ok i get it then i think, i should use internal or external ip address.

Comment: it themes you got it. If the PC is in same network, you can use internal PC IP. But make sure that you can access your backend from your Android device, for example using web-browser.

Comment: Bad Request , Invalid Hostname.
HTTP ERROR 400

why i couldn't connect ?

Comment: [Image 1](http://imgur.com/a/wFEVV)

[Image 2](http://imgur.com/a/m4Xio)

Comment: If i give my external iP - "Error connection timed out"

Comment: @VladMatvienko Can you give me your suggestion for this problem ?

Comment: nope, that is not android-side problem

Comment: @VladMatvienko Completed it by using Local IIS